# How to pass value to jquery dialog?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-dialog

How to get pass `id` value of `button` to `jquery dialog` on button click.
I don't want to pass value using `query string`.Is there any way that i can directly pass value using attributes or properties of `jquery dialog`.

View:

```
 <input type="button" value="Create New" class="Create" id="1"/>
```

Jquery:

```
 $(".Create").on("click", function (e) {
        var Id=$(this).atrr('id');
        $('#Load').empty();
        //overflow: visible !important;
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#Load').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,
            resizable: false,
            height: 500,
            width: 600,
            position: { my: "center", at: "center", of: window },
            dialogClass: 'fixed-dialog',
            title: 'Create New Word',
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).load("/Dictionary/_Create");
            },
            //close: function (event, ui) {
            //    window.location.href = window.location.href;
            //}
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: If you already have the `id` value, have you tried just using it in the `open` handler? As a side note, you should use `var id = this.id;` to get the `id`; no need to convert a DOM element to a jQuery object and then get the attribute, when you could use Vanilla JS...

Comment: any code plz , how you are suggesting to use by open handler?

Comment: `open: function (event, ui) { alert(Id); $(this).load("/Dictionary/_Create");}`

Comment: I can get the id value , as you have suggested but how i can pass this value to _Create partial view, I don't want to send this value using a query string i.e _Create?id=Id, since i don't want to mess up the code in the controller , Is there any solution so that I can directly pass value to _Create without passing value in query string?

Comment: Your question was not really clear. If I understand correctly, you want to send the `id` to the server. If so, then it really depends on what you are trying to accomplish. Do you need this `id` on the server? If so, then no, there is no other way but trough the query string. If you need the value only in the browser, you could, for example store it in a global variable or even in the `localStorage` or the `sessionStorage`.

Comment: yes i don't want to send this value to the server , I just want to send this value to popup , which is really a client side operation, no need to send value to server. Any code sample for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this line

```
var Id=$(this).atrr('id'); To BTW atrr is suppose to be attr 
CurrentId = $(this).attr('id'); without the var
```

Then in the page /Dictionary/_Create you can simple access the CurrentId variable using javascript since it's global

Comment: will come back after trying it.